# Implementing a generator/iter in python when reading a file

Tags: python, generator

consider the tab-separated file `foo.txt`:

```
chrY    1208806 1208908 +   .
chrY    1212556 1212620 +   .
chrY    1465479 1466558 +   .
```

The goal is to manipulate `foo.txt` to obtain `result.txt` as such:

```
chrY:1208806-1208908
chrY:1212556-1212620
chrY:1465479-1466558
```

This code works:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()[0:3]
        result = f'{l[0]}:{l[1]}-{l[2]}'
        print(result)
```

But what if `foo.txt` would be a giant file that cannot be fit into memory, saving every line in a list `l` wouldn't be feasible. How can I write the previous mentioned code into a `generator/iter` ?

Thanks.

Comment: file object is a lazy generator. The code is fine.

Comment: `open` in python returns a link to file not file content. So your code is fine.

Comment: but what about `l` ? can I split every line into a giant list ?

Comment: Do you mean result? If so, then no. Save it to 10K (just example) size of list. Then write to a file. (If you want to avoid the file-writing for every single line and want to do that in a single shot.)  'l' is just intermediate which is getting replaced in every iteration.

Comment: hum ok . could you show me how you would implement that in one shot then ?

Comment: There is only one thing to change in your current code: write to the output file instead of printing. It never has more than the current line loaded at any time.

Comment: @alex you don't. You create many smaller lists, each one only lasting for an iteration.

Comment: ```results = []
THRESHOLD = 10_000

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()[0:3]
        result = f'{l[0]}:{l[1]}-{l[2]}'
        results.append(result)
        if len(results) == THRESHOLD:
            write_to_output_file(results)
            results = []
```

Comment: oh I see `l` has no more than the current `line` iteration at any given time right ? my bad, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @lllrnr101 You're way overcomplicating it. Just use a buffer on the output file: `open('file.txt', 'w', buffering=bufsize)`

Comment: @flakes Python is already using buffering; explicitly specifying a buffer size, if one doesn't know EXACTLY what they are doing, can be counterproductive

Comment: @lllrnr101 _"Save it to 10K (just example) size of list. Then write to a file. (If you want to avoid the file-writing for every single line and want to do that in a single shot.)"_ afaict Python already has an efficient buffering mechanism acting behind the curtains, providing yours on top of Python's can be detrimental.

Comment: @gboffi Sure, I agree with you. The conversation here was suggesting writing your own in-mem buffer, which doesnt seem so pragmatic when its already built into the API.

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to do this in the past, to process files about 50GB+ in size. What you need to do is just write out each line as you process it.

```py
with open('foo.txt','r') as src, open('result.txt','w') as tgt:
    for line in src:
         l = line.split()[0:3]
         result = f'{l[0]}:{l[1]}-{l[2]}\n'
         tgt.write(result)
```

(note the inclusion of the newline character `\n` in `result`)

Processing large files takes a while this way, but there's barely any increase in RAM usage.

I just tested your example copied many times over, and it worked fine.

Comment: Consider using `with` statements. `with open('foo.txt', 'r') as src, open('result.txt','w') as tgt:`

Comment: just use `.write` not `.writelines` which is meant for a list of lines

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @flakes and @juanpa.arrivillaga! I've updated my answer to be more Pythonic.